# How to get and use Graph User Access Token for use in personal scripts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have written a Python script that makes some statistics for me and a couple of friends based on our posts and comments in them. I've been using it by getting a temporary token in Graph Explorer and copying it to the script before running it. So far I've been able to access friends' posts with API 1.0 (and for some time with 2.0, I assume that was a bug) but now the 1.0 API is getting closed and I'm running into an issue - while some of the /post requests are still accessible to me, many return an "Unsupported get request" error. I can only assume that I can't access these anymore unless I'm using their User Access Token.

I'm not sure what I can do now:

- ask them to use Graph Explorer to provide me a temporary token. It works, is pretty secure with default permissions but I would have to do it every time I wanted to update the data.
- make some sort of dummy app that they will log into once. I don't know if that violates any rules and if it will be removed immidetaly, I hope not. But I have no idea how to extract the user access token out of the app so I can use it in the script.

What's the "correct" way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If the App is only for a specific group of people, it should be no problem. Just **add your friends as Tester in the App** so they can **authorize it with the `read_stream` permission**. Else you would need to go through a review process, and Facebook usually does not approve `read_stream`.

You don´t really need to handle the Access Token, just use the JavaScript SDK and read the stream of your friends whenever they visit your App.

Btw, you can get the Access Token in the callback response of [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/). But it will only be valid for 2 hours, you can extend it to 60 days though. More information about extending Access Tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

**Easy solution**: Create an entry page where your friends (who are Testers in the App) can authorize with `read_stream`. Right after authorization or refreshing the Token with [FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/), read their posts and store them.

Here´s some code to get you started on that entry page: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

...of course you can also just let your friends generated the Access Token manually. Information about that can be found in the Facebook docs (see Link above) or (for example) here: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/ - they can then give you the Token, it will be valid for 60 days if it´s an extended one, or only 2 hours if it´s a default User Token.

Comment: "just use the JavaScript SDK and read the stream of your friends whenever they visit your App." so it's not really a dummy app anymore, as I would have to write some kind of JS front-end for that. Meanwhile I only really need to use the script once a week for 1-2 people at the same time, I copy the token, the script makes like a dozen of API requests and wraps results in a CSV file which I import to Excel afterwards. I don't see how JS comes into this. As for FB.login, that apparently needs to be embedded in an existing site with its URL added to app's settings.

Comment: well, that would be one basic html file with some javascript, nothing fancy...certainly a lot easier than generating the access token manually all the time. it´s not that easy to generate if you want an extended one.

Comment: not sure what you mean with "dozens of API requests", but with one token you can only get the posts of one single user - the one who generated the token. make sure you understand how tokens work.

Comment: to sum this up: i mean FB.login just for getting the access token in an easier way. example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: i´ve added some more information to my answer. that´s really all there is to know.